# Why are the pointers in my 64-bit ISAPI dll messed up?

Tags: pointers, 64-bit, isapi

I am working on migrating a 32-bit ISAPI dll to 64-bit.  I am using Visual Studio 2008.  I am having problems with the EXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK pointer in the HttpExtensionProc function.  The char pointers within the EXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK structure are not valid on entry into the function; they are labeled with  within the watch window.  If I manually modify the char pointers by swapping the first 4 bytes and the last 4 bytes of the pointer, the correct values display.  Any ideas why this would be happening?

This is the watch window before modifying the pointer, pay attention to lpszQueryString:
[link text](http://i41.tinypic.com/2rxwbr4.jpg)
[image]

This is the watch window after modifying the pointer, pay attention to lpszQueryString:
[link text](http://i39.tinypic.com/2hnar7n.jpg)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was building with 1-byte alignment.  I needed to do this:

```
#pragma pack(push, 8)
#include <httpext.h>
#pragma pack(pop)
```

[Thanks to nobugz for the answer.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/dac8de78-b987-4d1c-85ba-a8c5a98276c4)